# What Griffiths meant by "the potential is not unique"?

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, potential-energy, conventions

> The potential is not unique—any constant can be added to $V$ with impunity, since this will not affect its gradient.

> The vector potential is not unique—the gradient of any scalar function can be added to $A$ without affecting the curl, since the curl of a gradient is zero

What does the word "unique" represent here? We actually write that $-\vec \nabla V=\vec F$ I learned the expression from Classical Mechanics (while reading Goldstein's book on Classical Mechanics). But here Griffiths said that if $\vec \nabla \times \vec F = 0$ than we can write $\vec F = -\vec \nabla V$. Similar thing for Divergenceless. But the "unique" word doesn't tell me anything meaningful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context it just means that there is no single potential $U$ that describes the physics of the problem. There are infinitely many. If you give me a potential that describes the physics of the problem, let's call it $U_1$, I can give you a different potential $U_2$ that will give the exact same physics. I can easily do this by simply adding a constant $C$, i.e.
$$ U_2 = U_1 + C $$

Because $C$ is arbitrary, there are infinitely many potentials that describe the same physical setup. This is what he means by *not unique*. That there isn't a single one, but multiple "correct" potentials.

Comment: boring! blah! I can't accept it as correct answer in 4 minutes... :|

Comment: @AdilMohammed Tacking questions onto others in the comments is discouraged here, but feel free to open a new question and ask there.

Comment: Allright I'll delete in that case

Answer (score 2):

To be straightforward: he meant that there is not only one potential that physically describes the problem. Firstly, this seems like a mere curiosity, but it actually turns out to be more profound.

Mathematically, this can be seen by explicit computation. Whether you have a force $\vec{F}$ given by a potential energy $V$ through $\vec{F} = - \nabla V$ or if you have a static electric field $\vec{E}$ given in terms of a scalar potential $\phi$ through $\vec{E} = - \nabla \phi$, you have some freedom to redefine the potential. For example, if we consider $\phi' = \phi + c$, where $c$ is a constant, we have
$$\begin{align}
\vec{E'} &= -\nabla \phi', \\
&= -\nabla (\phi + c), \\
&= -\nabla \phi - \nabla c, \\
&= -\nabla \phi, \\
&= \vec{E}.
\end{align}$$
and hence both potentials lead to the same electric field. In Electrostatics or Mechanics, this can be seen as a choice of "reference potential". You can add a constant to choose that the potential should vanish at infinity, for example. Similar comments hold for the vector potential in magnetostatics.

When we consider Electrodynamics, though, the expressions for the fields in terms of the potentials become (see, e.g., Griffiths' Chap. 10)
$$
\begin{align}
\vec{E} &= - \nabla \phi - \frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t}, \\
\vec{B} &= \nabla \times \vec{A}.
\end{align}
$$

This gives us more freedom to redefine these fields. As Griffiths mentions on Chap. 10, the electric and magnetic fields are kept unchanged under transformations of the form
$$\phi' = \phi - \frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial t} \quad \text{and} \quad \vec{A'} = \vec{A} + \nabla \lambda,$$
for an arbitrary function $\lambda$. Both transformations should be carried at the same time, so the transformations cancel on the expression for the electric field. This shows that there is much more freedom on the choice of potentials than it initially looks like. We call these transformations *gauge transformations*, and invariance under gauge transformations is a symmetry of Electromagnetism. This symmetry turns out to lead to [quite deep results in Fundamental Physics](https://youtu.be/hF_uHfSoOGA). For example, the [conservation of electric charge can be traced back to it and it also requires the photon to be massless in order for it to hold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_conservation#Connection_to_gauge_invariance).

In short, the electromagnetic potentials are defined up to a choice of gauge. We have the freedom make some transformations to make the expressions more simple, without altering physical predictions. This is similar, *but not equal to*, our freedom of choosing a reference frame in which we'll work to study some Mechanics problem. This freedom also constitutes a symmetry of Electromagnetism and, [as pretty much any symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem), leads to quite profound physical consequences.

R. M. Wald's upcoming book [*Advanced Classical Electromagnetism*](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691220390/advanced-classical-electromagnetism) has an excellent discussion about these themes on its first chapter (which is conceptually advanced, despite not having any explicit computations). [A preview of this chapter is available at the publisher's website](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691220390/advanced-classical-electromagnetism#preview).

Answer (score 1):

Consider two vector potentials $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{A} + \nabla \phi$ for any differentiable scalar function $\phi$ such that $\nabla \times \vec{A} = \vec{F}$.

If you take the curl of the second potential, you get:
$$\nabla \times(\vec{A} + \nabla \phi) = \nabla \times \vec{A} + \nabla \times \nabla \phi$$
But the curl of the gradient of any appropriately differentiable scalar function is exactly $\vec{0}$:
$$\nabla \times \nabla \phi = \vec{0}$$
So for any such $\phi$, using $\vec{A}$ or $\vec{A} + \nabla \phi$ as a vector potential will yield the same $\vec{F}$; defining it either way doesn't influence what you actually care about, which is $\vec{F}$.